# Есть ли возможность сделать активной только часть объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для реализации одной из механик, которую я придумал, мне необходимо чтобы соблюдались определенные условия. Суть механики - это эфирные стены, если вы подобрали объект, который дает вам возможность с ними взаимодействовать, то состояние эфирных стен(отсутствие или наличие колладера, разные шейдеры) будет меняться, в зависимости от того, попадают ли они в радиус действия объекта. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при попадании в радиус менялось только состояние той части стен, которые непосредственно попадают в радиус, а остальной объект сохранял исходные свойства.

Comment: При слокновении со стеной, проверяйте расстояние до объекта, и если оно меньше требуемого, то принимайте нужно решение.

Comment: Уточните что за состояние... коллайдер?

Comment: @Yaroslav да, по большей части коллайдер, остальные моменты добавил в сам вопрос.

Comment: Как вариант можно делать стены из массива столбиков коллайдеров.